# Printing with Silverlight and com-interop

Tags: c#, silverlight, printing, com-interop

I'm trying to print from silverlight without a print dialog and for that I'm using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation;

Right now I'm creating a temporary txt file that contain the text to send to printer.

```
using (dynamic fso = AutomationFactory.CreateObject(@"Scripting.FileSystemObject"))
{
   dynamic file = fso.CreateTextFile(cFileName, true);
   file.Write(printText);
   file.Close();
}
```

After that I'm using shell.Aplication to print that document.

```
 dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");
 shell.ShellExecute(cFileName, "", "", "print", 1);
```

The question is, how can a print directly to printer without a temporary txt file?

Don't forget that I'm using Silverlight 4 out of browser and with elevated trust.

Comment: You can't.  No process is powerful enough to reach inside your process, knows its way around and obtain the string.  Don't sweat the small stuff, a file is not a problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant, isn't possible to print directly without using notepad? Besides using a temporary text file wich are the possible solutions to print the screen content?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start notepad and send your content although this is no fun solution:

Read: [Silverlight 4 - send text to Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985500/silverlight-4-send-text-to-notepad)
and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.85).aspx

So basicly, 
1. you start an instance of notepad. 
2. Wait some time.
3. Send your text to notepad
4. Send {PRTSC} for printing
5. Ofcourse, close the instance ;)

Good luck!

Comment: Isn't possible to print directly without using notepad? Besides using a temporary text file wich are the possible solutions to print the screen content?